# assertJSON test not working even though response JSON matches

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

My assertJSON test isn't working and says I get the below error

[image: json erro]

Here's the test code

```
$user = Sanctum::actingAs(
        User::factory()->create(),
        ['*']
    );

    $customer = Customer::first();

    $response = $this->getJson('api/customers/' . $customer->slug);

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertJson(
        [
            'data' => [
                'uuid'             => $customer->uuid,
                'customer_name'    => $customer->customer_name,
                'email'            => $customer->email,
                'slug'             => $customer->slug,
                'street_1'         => $customer->street_1,
                'street_2'         => $customer->street_2,
                'city'             => $customer->city,
                'postcode'         => $customer->postcode,
                'telephone_number' => $customer->telephone_number,
                'county'           => $customer->county,
                'customer_type'    => $customer->customerType,
                'archived'         => $customer->archived ? 'Yes' : 'No',
            ]
        ]
    );
```

And here is the customer resource

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'uuid'             => $this->uuid,
            'customer_name'    => $this->customer_name,
            'email'            => $this->email,
            'slug'             => $this->slug,
            'street_1'         => $this->street_1,
            'street_2'         => $this->street_2,
            'city'             => $this->city,
            'postcode'         => $this->postcode,
            'telephone_number' => $this->telephone_number,
            'county'           => $this->county,
            'customer_type'    => $this->customerType,
            'archived'         => $this->archived ? 'Yes' : 'No',
        ];
    }
```

The 2 JSON arrays are exactly the same and the other tests are working and everything on the front end is working just fine too.

More of the error

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Stupid question, is one a string and one a decoded object? I've had this where I've forgotten to json_decode() before.

Comment: That is to say... your test subject is an object or array, while the test is using assertJSON and failing because it isn't literal JSON?

Comment: Also, maybe look into testing a fragment instead: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/assertjson-isnt-seeing-the-json-that-is-being-returned